# Performing pct_change() that only considers the prior year in a time-series dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe "df":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2000, 2002, 2003, 2004], 
                   'Name': ['A'] * 4, 
                   'Value': [4, 1, 1, 3]})
```

When I perform pct_change() i.e.

```
df['change'] = df['Value'].pct_change()
```

The computed "change" value for row Year = 2002 is -0.75. How can I get Pandas to return a N/A for 2002 since data for 2001 is missing as I only wish to consider the immediate prior year in a time-series?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set_index` + `reindex` + `pct_change` with `fill_method=None` -

1. First, set `Year` as the index
2. Get a range of years from the minimum to maximum, and use this range to reindex the dataframe. Missing years are now added in as `NaN`s
3. Call `pct_change` on `Value` without padding `NaN`s.

```
r = np.arange(df.Year.min(), df.Year.max() + 1)
df = df.set_index('Year').reindex(r)
```

```
v = df['Value'].pct_change(fill_method=None)
df = df.assign(Change=v).dropna(how='all').reset_index()

df

   Year Name  Value  Change
0  2000    A    4.0     NaN
1  2002    A    1.0     NaN
2  2003    A    1.0     0.0
3  2004    A    3.0     2.0
```

Comment: Thanks. How can this solution be scaled to multiple "Name" IDs (e.g. "B", "C", etc.) with different range of Year values?

Comment: @user2530766 You can `groupby` `Name`. The code will need a little changing. Can you open a new question with an appropriate data sample?

Comment: Follow-up question for multiple IDs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960566/performing-pct-change-that-only-considers-the-prior-year-in-a-time-series-data