# Performing pct_change() that only considers the prior year in a time-series dataframe for multiple IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample dataframe "df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2000, 2002, 2003, 2004] + [1998, 1999, 2003, 2004],
                   'Name': ['A'] * 4 + ['B'] * 4,
                   'Value': [4, 1, 1, 3] + [34, 23, 22, 11]})
```

How can i use groupby "Name" and use the function "pct_change()" so that the function only considers the immediate prior year in my time-series? i.e. the function should return N/A in 2002 for name "A" (since year 2001 is missing) and in 2003 for name "B" (since year 2002 is missing)?